# Magento 2 How to change password length validation?

Tags: magento2, validation, password

I want to change the minimum length of password checking to 8. I tried changing `validation.js` `rules.js` but seems not work.

How can I change from 6 to 8?

Comment: I find it baffling that this wouldn't be a setting in the Magento 2 configuration. If it's not, it's definitely worth something contributing that change

Comment: It is a setting in the configuration, here's the official documentation: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/customers/password-options.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use jQuery validation in Magento 2. You can add this file in '.phtml' or '.js' file.

Let’s see how we can do this.

**1)** In input or select tag add our validation with this code:

```
data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-custom-pass':true}"
```

**2)** Add js validation for **Validate-custom-pass**

validation script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
'jquery', // jquery Library
'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
'jquery/validate', // Jquery Validation Library
'mage/translate' // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
], function($){ 
$.validator.addMethod(
'validate-custom-pass', function (value) { 
return (value.length >7); // Validation logic here modified length spelling
}, $.mage.__('Password length should be minimum 8'));

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 18):

This is a configuration item. In `Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Password Options` there's some options like `Password Length` and `Number of Required Character Classes`:

[image: Password Options in admin]
Above I set the minimum password length to 20 and below I get the message when trying to create an account:
[image: Warning message about password length]

Not sure at which version this was introduced but if you update your store to the latest version (I'm on 2.1.1) it will be available.

Comment: Do you confirm that it works for you? For me it does not work! Magento 2.1.2

Comment: I added images to my answer showing it works. Actually I'm on version 2.1.3 already

Comment: Thank you! It is probably a fix introduced in the new version 2.1.3. +1 for you for you availability.

Comment: It works for me in Magento 2.1.1. thanks

Comment: These options are not visible to me on Magento 2.2.2

Comment: @MJoraid I'm using M2.2.2 too, but I can find the options

Comment: @MohammedJoraid That's odd, perhaps you've selected a storeview as these are global configuration items? On 2.3.1 I can see these items exactly where I described

Comment: I'm not sure how I couldn't see them the other day. I'm now on 2.2.5 and 
I see them. Guess I was on the wrong page.

Comment: More reading: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/customers/password-options.html